# How to type a right pointing hand in a latex document?

Tags: symbols

For my control lecture, I like to include a right pointing hand in my LaTeX document. I have seen this in some Text Books and in MS-Word document, I insert symbol (Wingdings2: Character code 67) but in some text books I have seen better symbols of right pointing hand. I wish to do something similar for my lecture notes. Your help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ther are several fonts, or for even more choice just use `\includegraphics` with an image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are hand symbols in [`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\verb|\faHandPointRight|: \faHandPointRight

\verb|\faHandPointRight[regular]|: \faHandPointRight[regular]
\end{document}
```

The symbol output with `\faHandPointRight[regular]` (or at least a very similar one) is also available in [`fontawesome`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) as `\faHandORight`.

Answer (score 12):

There are several hand symbols in the [comprehensive symbol list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Here are a few examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bbding,pifont,utfsym,dingbat}

\begin{document}

Package \verb`bbding`: \HandRight

Package \verb`pifont`: \ding{43}

Package \verb`utfsym`: \usym{261E} 

Package \verb`dingbat`: \leftpointright 

Package \verb`dingbat`: \rightpointright 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `\verb\`...\`` rather that `\texttt`?

Comment: Not in this example.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the other answers, it's even an official Unicode character ☞ U+261E WHITE RIGHT POINTING INDEX. There should be quite a number of fonts supporting that glyph.